# Generating a session token

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, token, server-side

I'm working with a javascript file that makes an ajax call to a php file (a mail sender).

I don't want someone to build a bot that just calls the php page using the proper parameters, so I want one of the parameters to be a token string that the php can then compare to a string stored server-side.

So I made a php that creates a random string and saves it to storageSession, then echoes it.

My JS has an ajax call that runs that PHP file, in order to get the token... but for some reason, it doesn't.

Unfortunately, I can't write here from where I work, I cannot install chrome extensions (I'm not a programmer after all, just an editor who doesn't want to seed the website with the worst vulnerabilities out there) and I can't see the code from home.

I hope my memory is good.

```
function generateRandomString() {
  $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
  $String = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 20; ++$i) {
    $String .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
  }
  $_SESSION['token'] = $String;
  echo $String;
}


var myId;
$ajax(token){
  data: ''
  type: 'text'
  success{
    myId=token;
    console.log(myId);
}
```

the console shows "undefined".
Why?

Answer (score 4):

`$_SESSION` is an array. You must assign the variable this way :

```
$_SESSION['token'] = "myValue";
```

With `[]` not `()`. Also, don't forget to start your session on every page.
To generate a random token, if you are using PHP7, you may use [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

Which leads to something like that :

```
$_SESSION['token'] = random_bytes(12);
```

The pseudo code your give make hard to understand what the actual code is. Can you please provide the exact code (except for the token generation if you want to keep it secret)?

Also, you should not try to implement your own security system, developers, even seniors, always fail at it. For example, you can use [this library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), done by known cryptographic people.

Comment: @Zachiel "you should not try to implement your own security system"if you want security rather than the illusion of security.

Comment: I used the square brackets. Not having the code in front of me when posting here is really bad :( Anyway, should I really encrypt? I just want people to be unable to post unless they use my page, for my page generates a string and passes it server-side to the final point of the code. Why should I encrypt data?

Comment: The exploit you want to prevent is called a CSRF. And a token is a correct approach. There are plenty of good implementation out there, but also a lot of wrong ones. Check this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet which recommend this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFProtector_Project

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateRandomString() {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $String = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; ++$i) {
        $String. = $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    $_SESSION['token'] = $String;
    echo $String;
}
var myId;
$ajax(token) {
    data: ''
    type: 'text'
    success {
        myId = token;
        console.log(myId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you explain your solution?

Comment: It looks like you just added a } at the end... I'm pretty sure that was just me forgetting it when trascribing the code here, for I ran the original code through a validator and it was valid. If you have changed anything else, what is it? I can't spot it.